# jQuery if hasclass addclass

Tags: jquery, addclass

```
/* If the object is completely visible in the window... */
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
    $(this).is(".block-left").addClass('fadeInLeft');
    $(this).is(".block-right").addClass('fadeInRight');
}
```

I wand to addClass by checking the elements class, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) because `is()` returns a boolean value which will cause an error

```
$(this).filter(".block-left").addClass('fadeInLeft');
$(this).filter(".block-right").addClass('fadeInRight');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
    if($(this).hasClass("block-left")) {
        $(this).addClass("fadeInLeft");
    } else if($(this).hasClass("block-right")) {
        $(this).addClass("fadeInRight");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will add the class to all `.block-left` and `.block-right` elements, not just `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `if`

```
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
    if ($(this).is(".block-left")) {
        $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
    } else if ($(this).is(".block-right"))
        $(this).addClass('fadeInRight');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if($(this).hasClass("block-left")){
   $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
}
```